# A simple problem related with the following triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am stuck with the following problem that says :

> $O$ is any point inside $\triangle ABC$. Then I have to prove that

1. $AB+AC \gt OB+OC$
2. $AB+BC+CA \gt OA+OB+OC$

MY TRY: [image]

1. From $\triangle ABC$,$AB+AC \gt BC$ and from $\triangle OBC\,\,$,we get
   $\,\,OB+OC \gt BC$. Now ,I am not sure about how to proceed.
2. Considering the $\triangle AOB$,$\triangle BOC $,$\triangle AOC$, we get

   $OA+OB \gt AB\,\,,OB+OC \gt BC\,\,,OC+OA \gt AC\,\, $ respectively.

Now, combining all we get $2(OA+OB+OC) \gt (AB+BC+CA)$.

So,I am nowhere near the proof.
Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. :

Let $E$ be a point both on $OB$ and on $AC$.

[image]

From $\triangle{ABE}$, 
$$AB+AE\gt BO+OE\tag1$$

From $\triangle{OEC}$,
$$OE+EC\gt OC\tag2$$

Now the claim follows from $(1)+(2)$.

---

For 2. :

You can use 1. to prove that the inequality holds.

Comment: Thank you so much for neat explanation...

Comment: @learner: You are welcome.

Comment: @miracle173: Thank you for the addition.